# switching half an outlet

Tags: electrical

gregmac's terrific, detailed replies [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2836/how-can-i-make-an-outlet-switched?newreg=c110b15a0c22488db017baf336421be9) prompt a question for me. I have a switch mid-circuit that will control half of the next outlet downstream. There is one more outlet after that one, and it's the terminus of the circuit. After I've added the 3-wire romex between the switch and the second-to-last outlet, can I go back to 2-wire from that outlet to the last one?

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I do that all the time. I use my own "standard" conventions:

- Use the red wire for the "switched hot", black for "always hot".
- Make it the top half of the receptacle that is switched.
- Mark the switched half of the receptacle with a dot or something, to show it is switched.

Comment: Thanks Tom. So the always hot (unswitched supply) will feed into (3 wire) and out of (2 wire) the bottom receptacle, obviously. And I just nut off the neutrals, yes? (I'm a cabinetmaker, not an electrician - to paraphrase Dr. McCoy!)